# Problema con MySql en Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Cuando le doy start a MySql en Xampp me sale esta serie de errores

> MySQL Service detected with wrong path

```
15:41:54  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
15:41:54  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first 
15:41:54  [mysql]   Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" 
                     --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL
15:41:54  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
                     --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

alguien sabe como solucionarlo ?

Comment: Prueba esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718157/apache-mysql-service-detected-with-wrong-path-ports-already-in-use

Comment: parece que tenes la version 8 de mysql (`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe"`)  corriendo en memoria (`MySQL Service detected`), por eso la versión que viene con xampp (`c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe`) no puede arrancar. como dice el error desinstala o deshabilita la version actual o cambia la configuracion del xampp (`Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings`)